# openCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor function

Tags: c++, opencv

Using my pi-camera, I want to get a color picture.
so I use cvtColor function. but do not work well...

like this error msg -> [This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEg9e.jpg)
openCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)

and here is my code and error msg...

[Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96SfD.jpg)

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text, not as links to images.

Comment: you get grey images from your camera, you set it to CV_8UC1, which means one channel 8 bits per pixel per channel.. this means Greyscale. And please do not post code as image

Comment: You appear to be trying to capture in mono (CV8_UC1) i.e. singe channel then converting from colour to greyscale.

Comment: the error message means, that your image isn't 3 channel or 4 channel image. To convert from BGR to RGB, you do need 3 or 4 channels (clear, right?). Since you set the capture type to 8UC1, you do capture single channel images, wich you can't convert to RGB with that line of code. Try cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB instead, and test whether not image.empty() before you start working on the image.

Answer (score 1):

"scn" in this assertion is the number of channels in the image. You're attempting to convert a monochrome/grayscale (CV_8UC1) as if it were a 3- or 4- channel color image (scn == 3 || scn == 4). Use cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB to convert your grayscale image into one with 3 channels.